# C++ Remove First and Last digits of a number

Tags: c++, loops, counting, modulus

I am trying to write a program to get rid of the first and last digit of a number. For the last digit, diving an int by 10 solves that issue. I need to find a way to use % to remove the first digit, but it seems like my logic is off somewhere, my program runs but it doesn't work correctly. See any errors in logic?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;
    int y;
    cout << "Enter a number to have the first and last didgets removed" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    x /= 10;
    y = x;
    int count = 0;

    while (y > 1)
    {
        y /= 10;
        count++;
    }

    int newNum = x %(10 ^ (count));

    cout << newNum << endl; 
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues, but the key one is perhaps this:

```
int newNum = x %(10 ^ (count));
```

`^` is bitwise `xor`, it is *not* a power operator.

Instead, you can try something like this:

```
int newNum;
if (y < 10)
    newNum = 0; // or what should it be?
else
{
    int denominator = 1;
    while (y >= 10)
    {
        y /= 10;
        denominator *= 10;
    }
    newNum = x % denominator;
}
```

**P.S.** There are shorter and faster algorithms, but I tried to preserve the logic of the given one.

Comment: Thanks so much, I got it now. The only code I had to change was     int newNum = pow(10, count);
  x %= newNum;

  cout << x << endl;   Thank you for your help.

Comment: @XerradAnon I would not go for `pow`. What if due to rounding you get `9999.99...` instead of `10000`. Even if this does not happen in practice, the approach is dubious and risky.

Comment: @XerradAnon Also `while(y > 1)` does not look right. Try to test with numbers starting with `1` and with other digits.

Comment: I see what you mean, I got it working now with all numbers, before a serious of any number such as 55555 would display 5555 because of the rounding, and issues starting with 1. I removed the pow and set while (y>9.9).  Everything seems to be working right now. Thanks for all your input.

Comment: @XerradAnon `y > 9.9` is correct, but looks weird :). `y` is _integer_. So I'd suggest either `y > 9` or `y >= `10`.

Answer (score 2):

Another similar integer arithmetic solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;
    int y;
    cout << "Enter a number to have the first and last didgets removed" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    x /= 10;
    y = x;
    int count = 0;

    while (y > 9) {
        y /= 10;
        ++count;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        y *= 10;
    x -= y;

    cout << x << endl; 
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for using my code and fixing what needed to be done, it made it a lot easier to understand the logic since most of it is what I did I can follow what you fixed with it easily.

Answer (score 1):

I foud the answer how to remove first digit [here](http://%20http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/120186/#msg653946).

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

void remove_first(int &num) {
    num %= static_cast<int>(pow(10, static_cast<size_t>(log10(num))));
}
```

Essentially it does this `x % (10 ^ floor(log10(x)))`.

To remove the last digit just divide the nubmer by 10 and take the whole part (`floor(x / 10)`) as you planned originally.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h=0, bb, sum;
    cin>>n;
    d=n;
    b=n/10%10;
    while(n>99) {
        n=n/10;
        c=n/10;
        c=n%10;
        g=(n/10)/(n/10);
        h=h+g;
    }
    a=b;
    f=d-(a*10)+(c*10);
    while(d>99)
        d=d/10;
    switch(h)
    {
        case 2: bb=100; break;
        case 3: bb=1000; break;
        case 4: bb=10000; break;
        case 5: bb=100000; break;
        case 6: bb=1000000; break;
        case 7: bb=10000000; break;
        case 8: bb=100000000; break;
        case 9: bb=1000000000; break;
    }
    e=f-(f/bb)*bb;
    sum=((d/10)*10+(a))*bb+e;
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```